# Radial basis functions for spectral solution of PDE in spherical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, galerkin-methods, radial-basis-functions

I want to solve the following PDE defined in 3D-space and time:

$(z \partial_t-F(t)\partial_z)f(t,\vec{x})+C[f]=S(t,z,r),$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $C[f]$ is a linear integral operator. The details of this equation are not very important. What is important is that, by symmetry, the solution should not depend on the azimuthal angle $\phi=\arctan(y/x)$.

To solve this PDE, I wanted to use a spectral method and use the expansion
$f(t,\vec{x})=\sum\limits_{m,n} a_{mn}(t)b_m(r)c_n(\theta)$, which already respects the symmetry of the equation. For the angular part, I think the most natural choice would be the spherical harmonics of order $0$: $c_n(\theta)=Y_n^0(\theta)=P_n(\cos\theta)$, but I'm not sure what basis functions to use for the radial part. I've looked in the literature, and I wasn't able to find a simple solution: most studies focus on problems defined in polar coordinates or on a spherical shell, which avoids the singularity of spherical coordinates at the origin.

I did find similar radial basis functions for problems in polar coordinates in [this paper](http://cfd.me.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/A-Spectral-Method-for-Unbounded-Domains.pdf). Would it be possible to use the same basis in my situation? If not, is there another set of basis functions that would be appropriate for this problem?

Thanks!